# nodejs connect mssql by using node-mssql

Tags: sql-server, node.js, node-sqlite3

I try to use node-mssql(https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/issues) to connect mssql.
Here is my config:

```
export class Config {
   static db = {

    server: ...,
    user: ....,
    password: ....,
    database:...,

  }
}
```

Here is my connection code

```
sql.connect(Config).then(function(){
    new sql.Request().query('SELECT * FROM ABC_2016.dbo.device')        .
                     .then(recordset=>console.log(recordset))
                     .catch(err =>console.log(err));
```

Here is my error:
(intermediate value).query(...).then is not a function.

I have no idea why this happen!!

Somebody helps me!

Comment: have u entered correct database connection details?

Answer (score 0):

try using the multiconnection method ...

it's like this :

```
var conn1 = new sql.Connection(config, function(error){
    if(error){
        console.log(error)
    } else {
       var request = new sql.Request(conn1);

        request
        .input('project_id', sql.Int,project_id)
        .query('SELECT * from TableName WHERE [project_id] = @project_id ORDER BY [id] ')
        .then(function(data) { 
            console.log(data)
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }); 
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method

```
var webconfig = {

user: 'login',

password: 'sa@123',

server: 'localhost', 

database: 'TestDB',



options: {

    encrypt: false // Use this if you're on Windows Azure 

}

  }




 var express = require('express');

 var sql = require('mssql');

 var http = require('http');




 var app = express();

 var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;




 var connection = new sql.Connection(webconfig, function(err) {

var request = new sql.Request(connection); 

request.query('select * from Users', function(err, recordset) {

   if(err)      // ... error checks 

        console.log('Database connection error');



console.dir("User Data: "+recordset);

});

 });


  app.listen(port);

  console.log(port+' is the magic port');
```

or visit here https://nodejsbeginersprograms.blogspot.in/2017/02/nodejs-basic-tutorial-with-mssql.html